# Should user of C# function should always create new instance of delegate instead of reusing

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have API similar to following, which takes delegate to report the progress of operation.  Also returns the task so that it can be cancelled.

If user of this function uses the same delegate instance for multiple function calls, how does user 
determine which progress is for which function invocation.

```
class Program
{
    public static Task LongOperationAsync(List<String> names, Action<String> progress)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           foreach (var item in names)
           {
               // do some long operation
               progress(item.ToUpper());
           }
       });

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var friends = new List<String>() {"joey","ross","chandler","monica","phoebe","rachel" };
        var seinfelds = new List<String>() { "Jerry", "kramer", "george", "elaine" };

        Action<String> resultProcessor = (result) =>
        {
            // process the result. let's say update the UI as and when results arrive
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        };
        var task1 = LongOperationAsync(friends, resultProcessor);
        var task2 = LongOperationAsync(seinfelds, resultProcessor);
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: You could redefine progress as `Action<object, string> progress` and then include the object which the progress belongs to in the calls to the action.

Comment: Sidenote: you should probably use Task.Run and not Factory.Startnew: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I have 2 questions

Actually, I see three. Here's your first one (the lack of a question mark doesn't keep it from being a question :) ):

> how does user determine which progress is for which function invocation.

How do you want the user to determine that? With the code you posted, it simply wouldn't be possible. There are a variety of ways you could fix that, but if you are talking about re-using the same delegate instance, you'll have to modify the called method:

```
public static Task LongOperationAsync(List<String> names, Action<String> progress, string id)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       foreach (var item in names)
       {
           // do some long operation
           progress($"{id}: {item.ToUpper()}");
       }
   });
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var friends = new List<String>() {"joey","ross","chandler","monica","phoebe","rachel" };
    var scienfelds = new List<String>() { "Jerry", "kramer", "george", "elaine" };

    Action<String> resultProcessor = (result) =>
    {
        // process the result. let's say update the UI as and when results arrive
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    };
    var task1 = LongOperationAsync(friends, resultProcessor, "task1");
    var task2 = LongOperationAsync(scienfelds, resultProcessor, "task2");
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or a related alternative, if you want for the callback itself to be able to know which task the progress is for:

```
public static Task LongOperationAsync(List<String> names, Action<String, String> progress, string id)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       foreach (var item in names)
       {
           // do some long operation
           progress(item.ToUpper(), id);
       }
   });
}
```

Your other questions are "primarily opinion-based" and so not really suitable for Stack Overflow, but since I'm writing anyway, here's my two cents:

> •Is it always good practices to take user provided info for a function which takes delegate ( Action or Func) ?

Always? No. It depends on context.

> •Is is recommended to reuse the delegate instance across multiple function calls ?

This also depends on context. If you can do so conveniently, or if you are in a scenario where otherwise an enormous number of delegate instances would have to be created, then you should probably reuse an instance.

But as long as there's no serious performance issue (and usually there wouldn't be), you should write the code in the way that makes the most sense, rather than worrying about creating the object.

For example, an alternative to your code, in which the delegate is *not* reused, would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var friends = new List<String>() {"joey","ross","chandler","monica","phoebe","rachel" };
    var scienfelds = new List<String>() { "Jerry", "kramer", "george", "elaine" };

    Action<String, String> resultProcessor = (result, id) =>
    {
        // process the result. let's say update the UI as and when results arrive
        Console.WriteLine($"{id}: {result}");
    };
    var task1 = LongOperationAsync(friends, r => resultProcessor(r, "task1"));
    var task2 = LongOperationAsync(scienfelds, r => resultProcessor(r, "task2"));
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In this way, the callback is customized for the needs of the client code, without requiring a change to the callee (i.e. without requiring a change to `LongOperationAsync()`). The callee can remain agnostic about what types of callers there might be.

Yes, you wind up having to create additional delegate instances. But so what? You've got a long operation here. You're not going to be creating even a dozen of them in a second, never mind the tens of thousands it would require before the performance issues even start to become an issue, never mind really *have* to be solved.